# What are the most feasible options to do processing on google books n-gram dataset using modest resources?

Tags: hadoop, hive, distributed-computing, bigdata, n-gram

I need to calculate word co-occurrence statistics for some 10,000 target words and few hundred context words, for each target word, from n-gram corpus of google books

Below is the link of the full dataset:

[Google Ngram Viewer](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html)

As evident database is approximately of 2.2TB and contains few hundred billions of rows. For computing word co-occurrence statistics I need to process the whole data for each possible  pair of target and context word . I am currently considering  using Hadoop with Hive for batch processing of data. What are the other viable options considering this is an academic project with  time constraints of a semester and limited availability of computational resources.

Note that real time querying on the data is not required

Comment: Some form of MapReduce seems like the right approach.

Comment: http://lintool.github.com/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf should prove useful

Answer (score 0):

Hive has a built-in UDF for handling ngrams
https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/statisticsanddatamining.html#StatisticsAndDataMining-ngrams%2528%2529andcontextngrams%2528%2529%253ANgramfrequencyestimation

Comment: I guess this will involve writing lot of queries